# ASPxTreeList expand/collapse root node when Selection Changed

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I need to call dvxTreeList.ExpandNode(key) after node has been selected, but I can't figure out how to get this "key".

Is there any way to get a node that was just checked in the DevExpress ASPxTreeList control?
The ClientSideEvents.SelectionChanged handler seems have nothing according to this in the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you select a node by clicking it, you can handle the [ASPxClientTreeList.NodeClick](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListScriptsASPxClientTreeList_NodeClicktopic)
event and get node key in e.nodeKey property.
If you checking selection check boxes to select a node you can enable the TreeListSettingsBehavior.ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer setting, handle the ASPxTreeList.SelectionChanged event and get a selected node using the ASPxTreeList.GetSelectedNodes mehod and save its key on the server side. When yuor end-user selects another note, the event will be raised. Get new list of selected nodes and compare it with the saved one. If there are a new node, it has been just selected.

You can use the TreeListNode.MakeVisible method to expand a required node.

Also see [this example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E325)

Comment: Thank you, but NodeClick firing if I click label, but not checkbox. When checked state is changing, NodeClick not firing at all.

Comment: If I do it on the server side, I still need to know what node was just clicked, because I can't check all selected nodes as some of them maybe checked and collapsed, I don't need to expand manually collapsed nodes...